# Resorting Of List Moving Up and Down

Tags: c#, generic-list

I am using an observation collection to store a list that I bound to a WPF Listview, my problem is that I am trying to get the front end order working. At the min If I click my move up button its moving the item up ok but its not changing the already populated items in the list. This should be easy but im finding it hard.

My Question is how do i correctly change the order number position to reflect after the user as clicked the mouse up button based on the below sequences  and updating the other items in the list to reflect the new position, as at present its not changing the number correclty's for existing elements or the new additional element.

```
  Order     Display Name     Width
  1         Title            50
  2         Description      150
```

I add a item onto the list using add button

```
  Order     Display Name     Width
  1         Title            50
  2         Description      150 
  3         Newitem          50
```

I click the move up button once the new list order becomes

```
  Order     Display Name     Width
  1         Title            50
  2         Newitem          50 
  3         Description      150
```

The code im using is as follows

```
    ObservableCollection<CustomColumnsModel> columnsList = this.WizardData.ConcreteCustomColumnsProxy;
    Extensions.MoveItemUp(columnsList, this.listView1.SelectedIndex);

    int offset = 0;
    var selectedColumnItem = listView1.SelectedItem as CustomColumnsModel;

    foreach (CustomColumnsModel item in columnsList)
    {

        foreach (CustomColumnsModel item in this.listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            item.CustomColumnsOrder -= 1;
        }else if (listView1.SelectedItem > item)
        {
                item.CustomColumnsOrder +1;
        }



    }
```

The following is my extension method

```
  public static void MoveItemUp<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> baseCollection, int selectedIndex)
    {
        //# Check if move is possible
        if (selectedIndex <= 0)
            return;

        //# Move-Item
        baseCollection.Move(selectedIndex - 1, selectedIndex);
    }
```

And this is my poco class

```
 public class CustomColumnsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public const string IdPropertyName = "CustomColumnsID";
    private Guid _Id = Guid.Empty;
    public Guid CustomColumnsID
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set
        {
            if (_Id == value)
                return;
            _Id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(IdPropertyName);
        }
    }


    public string CustomColumnsDisplayName { get; set; }
    public int CustomColumnsWidth { get; set; }
    public int CustomColumnsOrder { get; set; }  


    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string key)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(key));
        }
    }

    public EnterpriseManagementObject ActualData { get; private set; }
```

Edit to show code tried based on suggestion

```
  foreach (CustomColumnsModel item in columnsList)
    {

         if (item.CustomColumnsOrder < item.ColumnIndex)
         item.CustomColumnsOrder -= 1;
         else if (item.CustomColumnsOrder > item.ColumnIndex)
         item.CustomColumnsOrder -= 1;
   }
```

Comment: so, whats' your question?

Comment: @Noctis ADD QUESTION above in edit their sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you'll need to have an index property on your objects, and whenever someone hit's `up` , if it's not the top one, you'll have to swap the index number with the index number of the one above it.

When someone hits `down` if it's not the lowest, then swap items again.

> order id val
>   1  . . .        1 .  one
>   2  . . .        2 .  two
>   3  . . .        3 .  three

will become (assuming you hit up on 3):

> order id val
>   1 . . .    1 .  one
>   3 . . .         2  . two
>   2 . . .         3 .  three

Then just sort them by order.

---

**Edit**:

```
    // The following will never be smaller than 0
    if (selectedIndex <= 0)
        return;

    // This is not really doing what you want. 
    baseCollection.Move(selectedIndex - 1, selectedIndex);
```

You want to have a var `item_to_move_up` which is equal to the item in your selected index, and one `item_to_move_down` that is the one above it (assuming you checked in the logic it's not the first).
Next,swap their order values. Something like:

```
var temp_val = item_to_move_up.order;
item_to_move_up = item_to_move_down.order;
item_to_move_down = temp_val;
```

Comment: could you provide a code example by any chance thanks then can mark your answer as correct

Comment: The answer is correct either way. This site is for helping you out, not for writing your code for you ...

Comment: No but most would provide a short example of their implmentation to help thats all I ment

Comment: There's not much to that method. All you need to do, is look at the selected index of object you're clicking `up` on, look at it, fetch the object with (index-1), and swap the order on the object's id.

Comment: I updated my code to show what i tried with the index but i dont think i have the logic down here sorry

Comment: i still not got this down yet just i find logic things like this hard myself

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older post.
But, in case anyone ends up here...

Here is an example of what I do.

[image: ui - example sorting a collection]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
    {
        new Student(){ name="Jimmy" },
        new Student(){ name="Billy" },
        new Student(){ name="Sarah" },
        new Student(){ name="Bobby" },
        new Student(){ name="Garry" },
        new Student(){ name="Eva" },
        new Student(){ name="Nancy" }
    };
    private Student _student;

    private class Student
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveUpDn(true);
    }
    private void MoveUpDn(bool blnUp)
    {
        if (_student == null) return;
        int idx = students.IndexOf(_student);
        if (blnUp)
        {
            if (idx <= 0) return;
            students.Insert(idx - 1, _student);
            students.RemoveAt(idx + 1);
            idx--;
        }
        else
        {
            if (idx >= students.Count - 1) return;
            students.Insert(idx + 2, _student);
            students.RemoveAt(idx);
            idx++;
        }
        UpdateMyList();
        this.listBox1.SelectedIndex = idx;
    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateMyList();
    }
    private void UpdateMyList()
    {
        this.listBox1.DataSource = null;
        this.listBox1.DataSource = students;
        this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null) return;
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem.GetType() != typeof(Student)) return;
        Student student = this.listBox1.SelectedItem as Student;
        if (student == null) return;
        _student = student;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveUpDn(false);
    }
}
}
```